# NetBeans Color Scheme doesn't work for CSS

Tags: netbeans, color-scheme

I use NetBeans 7.3.1 for coding with Monster Color scheme. It works fine with HTML or PHP files, but not coloring CSS.

When I tried to set colors manually, there are no options for CSS in settings.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Does anyone met with same problem?